# Difference between linux file system and directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, terminology

I am bit confused between "file systems" and "directories" in Linux.

- What is the difference and
- when do I need to create file system and mount it while I can simply create a directory ?

Comment: In what are you going to "simply" create this directory?

Comment: Filesystems and directories are not comparable - directories are a *feature* of filesystems. You can't have a directory without a filesystem.

Comment: I would recommend to go through the standard blog of redhat file system and directory creation . Anyways we can't create directories without creating file systems on volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a basic level, a filesystem is a tree structure of one or more directories whose storage capacity is tracked as a unit. (This is complicated by advanced filesystems like ZFS or BtrFS, which can have subvolumes and other LVM and/or RAID functionality integrated to the filesystem.)

Usually you'll want *as few filesystems as you can get away with*, to avoid the situations when your disk space allocation assumptions turn out to be incorrect and your free disk capacity is not in the filesystem you need it in.

On the other hand, you'll want to split a part of a directory tree structure into a separate filesystem when:

- you want the ability to preserve that part through a major upgrade or even total OS reinstallation (e.g. `/home`), or want it on a separate disk/set of disks so it can be physically moved from one computer to another independent of the rest of the directory tree.
- you *want* that part of the directory tree to have an independent allocation of disk space, so running out of space in one particular part of the directory tree won't cause problems to other parts of the system using other parts of the directory tree (e.g. `/tmp` and/or `/var/tmp` in multi-user systems, `/var/log` when you need to do extensive logging, a dedicated space for some program that's still in development phase and known to occasionally freak out and produce a huge mess of temporary files it won't automatically clean...)
- you need the features of a particular type of filesystem for e.g. some specific data files only (e.g. that multi-terabyte dataset that needs snapshotting capability to have a chance to back it up without an unreasonable amount of downtime)
- you want to use some special mount options for some specific part of the directory tree that would be difficult or impossible if used over the whole system (`nodev`, `noexec`, etc.)